# I can't figure out how to stop this from being printed

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, printing

First time on here and pretty much my first time coding, sorry if this doesn't fit but nothing I've tried has worked. Basically, the program is supposed to print numbers 1-100 but every time there is a multiple of 3 it prints Fizz, every 5 it prints Buzz and for both it prints FizzBuzz. At the very end of the print, it always puts 101 and I can't figure out how to stop this. The whole thing is a lot of guesswork because I don't really know what I'm doing, so help is appreciated.

```
answer = int(1)
limit = int(100)
three: int = (3)
five: int = (5)
while answer < 100:
    if limit >= answer:
        if answer >= three and answer >= five:
            print("FizzBuzz")
            answer = answer + 1
            three = three + 3
            five = five + 5
        if answer >= three:
            print("Fizz")
            answer = answer + 1
            three = three + 3
        if answer >= five:
            print("Buzz")
            answer = answer + 1
            five = five + 5
        if not answer >= five or answer >= three:
            print (answer)
            answer = answer + 1
```

This is the result:

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
6
Fizz
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz
16
17
Fizz
19
Buzz
21
Fizz
23
Fizz
Buzz
26
Fizz
28
29
FizzBuzz
31
32
Fizz
34
Buzz
36
Fizz
38
Fizz
Buzz
41
Fizz
43
44
FizzBuzz
46
47
Fizz
49
Buzz
51
Fizz
53
Fizz
Buzz
56
Fizz
58
59
FizzBuzz
61
62
Fizz
64
Buzz
66
Fizz
68
Fizz
Buzz
71
Fizz
73
74
FizzBuzz
76
77
Fizz
79
Buzz
81
Fizz
83
Fizz
Buzz
86
Fizz
88
89
FizzBuzz
91
92
Fizz
94
Buzz
96
Fizz
98
Fizz
Buzz
101
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing multiple "checks" as `if`, make all of them besides the first `elif`, meaning "else (the first one it attempts), if [your condition for the second one]"

It also fixes some "bugs" you had with numbers that are divisible by 3 or 5 but wouldn't show the works. Take 81 as an example, your output had the 81, mine has the word Fizz since, well, 81 is divisible by 3 (27)

Change your `if` statements to `elif`, worked for me when I tested:

```
answer = int(1)
limit = int(100)
three: int = (3)
five: int = (5)
while answer < 100:
    if limit >= answer:
        if answer >= three and answer >= five:
            print("FizzBuzz")
            answer = answer + 1
            three = three + 3
            five = five + 5
        elif answer >= three:
            print("Fizz")
            answer = answer + 1
            three = three + 3
        elif answer >= five:
            print("Buzz")
            answer = answer + 1
            five = five + 5
        elif not answer >= five or answer >= three:
            print (answer)
            answer = answer + 1
```

My output:

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz
16
17
Fizz
19
Buzz
Fizz
22
23
Fizz
Buzz
26
Fizz
28
29
FizzBuzz
31
32
Fizz
34
Buzz
Fizz
37
38
Fizz
Buzz
41
Fizz
43
44
FizzBuzz
46
47
Fizz
49
Buzz
Fizz
52
53
Fizz
Buzz
56
Fizz
58
59
FizzBuzz
61
62
Fizz
64
Buzz
Fizz
67
68
Fizz
Buzz
71
Fizz
73
74
FizzBuzz
76
77
Fizz
79
Buzz
Fizz
82
83
Fizz
Buzz
86
Fizz
88
89
FizzBuzz
91
92
Fizz
94
Buzz
Fizz
97
98
Fizz
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your loop doesn't return to the start after it prints something, after it adds 1 to 100 (getting 101), it will then check the next if using answer = 101.

You want to either use elifs instead of ifs so that only 1 if block will be executed (though you should be sure they're checked in the correct order), or a continue at the end of each if block.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you shorten the sequence to 10 and then step through your code and watch what happens, especially when you get to 9. You might think there is one `print` that gets run on each `while` loop, but in fact `print` will often be run multiple times on each `while` loop. That's because you have multiple `if` statements, rather than using `elif`, as other have pointed out.

Suppose you reach the state at which
limit is 100
answer is 99
five is 100
three is 99

Your while condition and first if condition are both true.

```
while answer < 100:
    if limit >= answer:
```

Then the next `if` condition is tested:

```
        if answer >= three and answer >= five:
```

Not true (`answer` is less than `five`).

But then you hit the next `if`:

```
        if answer >= three:
            print("Fizz")
            answer = answer + 1
            three = three + 3
```

The condition is true, and so this block is run. After the `print`, `answer` is incremented to 100, and `three` is incremented to 102.

Since you didn't use `elif`s, you continue through the `while` loop block. So, the next `if` is tested:

```
        if answer >= five:
            print("Buzz")
            answer = answer + 1
            five = five + 5
```

The condition is true, so that block is run. After the `print`, `answer` is incremented to 101, and `five` is incremented to 105.

Finally, you get to the last `if` in the `while` loop:

```
        if not answer >= five or answer >= three:
            print (answer)
            answer = answer + 1
```

At this point, you're not comparing `answer` with `limit` or with `100`. That's because you assumed that was happening in the `while` statement. This condition is true and so this block will get run. Hence `print(101)`.

As suggested by others, changing to `elif`s will fix things.

But there are other improvements you can make

```py
for i in range(1, 101): # start, stop -- stop won't be included
    if i % 5 == 0 and i % 3 == 0:
        print("FizzBuzz")
    elif i % 5 == 0:
        print("Buzz")
    elif i % 3 == 0:
        print("Fizz")
    else:
        print(i)
```

Note that you don't have to use `int(n)` to assign a number. You only need to use `int()` to convert a float or number string to an integer.

The `range(1, 101)` function generates a sequence from 1 to 100, and the `for` statement will loop once for each value in the range. You don't need to increment anything within the loop.

`%` is the modulo operator—it gives the remainder after division. For example, `9 % 5` equals 4; `10 % 5` equals 0. So `if i % 5 == 0` will be true whenever `i` is a multiple of 5.

The `if... elif` pattern ensures that only one of the nested blocks is executed on each loop of the `for` loop.